# Is this simple cast safe when saving records?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

For most of my models in CakePHP I often create a function that handles saving a record. The default behavior for a Model's save is to return the data array or false.

I prefer the function to return true/false only. So I cast the result to (bool). Is this a valid way to cast something to boolean?

It's never *not* worked, but I've often wondered if it was a poor practice.

```
public function queue($url,$order=0)
{
    $result = $this->save(array(
        $this->alias => array(
            'agg_domain_id' => $domain_id,
            'order' => $order,
            'url' => $url
        )
    ));

    return (bool)$result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a valid way to cast something to boolean?

### Yes

It's fine to do that where you only want to know success or fail.

### When it's not ok

The only potential problems with casting the return value like that, is if the return value could be a falsey type e.g.:

```
array()
0
""
" "
```

a call to save always returns a nested array or false - there is no scope for getting a false-negative result with a call to save.

Comment: Thanks, this was the clarification I was seeking. A false-negative was what I feared.

Answer (score 5):

From php.net:

> To explicitly convert a value to boolean, use the (bool) or (boolean) casts. However, in most cases the cast is unncecessary, since a value will be automatically converted if an operator, function or control structure requires a boolean argument.

So if you do `if($this->queue('url',0))` then the cast is not necessary.

But if you do `if($this->queue('url',0) === true)` then you need to cast. And casting with `(bool)` is absolute legitimate.